# Escaping Escape Sequences

Tags: c#, xml, escaping

So I'm writing an application that formats Xml files that will be compared to another Xml file.  However, I'm stuck on trying to escape ' within only the Value field.  How do can I tell it to replace `'` `with &apos`, and not `&amp;apos;` ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, nor why you appear to be doing all of this manually instead of using XML APIs. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Your answer should be an edit to this question.  I don't think you can do what you want, primarily because `'` doesn't require escaping in XML.  You can set `InnerXml` to `&apos;`, but it will simply be converted back to `'`.  The rest of the escape sequences, `XmlElement` will handle for you - which is why you're seeing everything double escaped. Your code isn't necessary.